# Non-blocking input stream during run

Tags: java, c++, console-application

Working on project console program, that needs an infinite loop, stopped by a key while the process is running , such as 'q', or 'Esc' key, and requires an action uses arrow keys such as Up key to do something , and Down key. There is in C/C++ a `getch()`, but I found after search , there's no equivalent in Java.

Comment: Your target is java, right? Clarify please ...

Comment: yes, Java console Application .

Comment: i need to get the output screen at the execution of that statement, or something equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.in.read()` will read one bye typed, waiting until one appears before returning.
(for more complex input this will not be enough as it doesn't handle multi byte characters, should be fine for you though...)

Comment: `read()` only reads a single byte, not necessarily a whole character (which can be 2 bytes or more depending on the encoding)

Comment: True. All the standard characters will be covered which should be enough for the Op though.